# Curb curb-fu gem installation problem

Tags: ruby, libcurl, curb

I've installed the Curb and Curb-fu gem and libcurl on my Ubuntu box.

If I go into irb and run the following

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'curb'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> require 'curb-fu'
=> true
irb(main):005:0>
```

So it seems that I have access to all the gems.

But I've created a very simple ruby app that's giving me an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'curb'
require 'json'
require 'curb-fu'

response = CurbFu.get('http://slashdot.org')
puts response.body
```

I get the following error back.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/curb-fu-0.4.4/lib/curb-fu/authentication.rb:3: uninitialized constant CurbFu::Authentication::Curl (NameError)
```

I have a feeling it's something to do with libcurl and have tried several different versions but still no joy.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Cheers

Togs

Comment: I believe, that if it was for libcurl libraries, you wouldn't be able to install curb gem. You can always try reinstalling libcurl and libcurl-dev packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it to work.

I uninstalled both the curb and curb-fu gem and re-installed them.

I now have curb-fu working.

For future reference for anyone having problems with this.. these are the libcurl bits I installed.

```
libcurl3
libcurl3-gnutls
libcurl4-openssl-dev
```